# How to allow only one / in angular pattern?

Tags: angularjs, pattern-matching

I want to allow only / in angular pattern

For Example, When user inputs "Test Name/VIP" this should be validated correctly format. But if user inputs like "Test Name VIP" or "Test Name, VIP" the pattern should show error.

Only "TestName/VIP" should be format for validating true. Is there any regex to validate it.

Comment: Why don't you write your own regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

maybe a regex is too much, just test the string for these rules

it's length is 3 or greater -> `myString.length>=3`
it has the character '/' inside

```
if(myString.indexOf('/') === -1) {
// no slash found
}
```

like so

```
if (myString.length>=3 && myString.indexOf('/') > -1) {
    // validate
}
```